# Rule creation on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I am facing the problem with the created rules.

**Requirement:** I created 3 status drop down values, ie. `temp1`,`temp2`, and `temp3`. While updating `status` to `temp1` - `starttime1` should be updated with current time. Again updating from `temp1` to `temp2` - `starttime2` should be updated with curent time,

**Issue**: When i tried to update the status from `temp1` to `temp2`, both `starttime1` and `starttime2` are updated with `starttime2`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario. To avoid this phenomenon, you could add an action to make read-only to `starttime1` when set current time to `starttime2`. Check my example below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but our problem is we can change the value of text box to empty as per our requirement.If we apply this rule to make the field as read only, it is saving with empty, how this rule works in this scenario?

Comment: You could use `Clear the value of ...` rule instead of `Make read-only...` rule.